# "systemd --now enable metricbeat.service" isn't starting metricbeat.service

Tags: debian, systemd

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
9.8
# uname -a
Linux X 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# 
# systemctl --version
systemd 232
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
# 
# metricbeat version
metricbeat version 6.7.1 (amd64), libbeat 6.7.1 [1d55b4bd9dbf106a4ad4bc34fe9ee425d922363b built 2019-04-02 15:11:28 +0000 UTC]
#
```

I'm trying to use `systemctl` with `--now` flag, yet running into following:

`systemctl`:

```
# systemctl --now enable metricbeat
Synchronizing state of metricbeat.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable metricbeat
# echo $?
0
# systemctl status metricbeat
● metricbeat.service - Metricbeat is a lightweight shipper for metrics.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/metricbeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/metricbeat
#
```

however, if/when I start service using just `systemctl start`, service starts:

```
# systemctl start metricbeat
# echo $?
0
# systemctl status metricbeat
● metricbeat.service - Metricbeat is a lightweight shipper for metrics.
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/metricbeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-04-10 20:08:40 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/metricbeat
 Main PID: 21369 (metricbeat)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 9.9M
      CPU: 167ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/metricbeat.service
           └─21369 /usr/share/metricbeat/bin/metricbeat -c /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/metricbeat -path.config /etc/metricbeat -path.data /var/lib/metricbeat -path.logs /var/log/metricbe

Apr 10 20:08:40 X systemd[1]: Started Metricbeat is a lightweight shipper for metrics..
#
```

actual question:

why `--now` isn't working? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does metricbeat not have a proper systemd unit? You should be very worried when some purportedly modern software still expects you to run an old-style /etc/init.d/ script.

Comment: @MichaelHampton are you saying `--now` isn't working due to service using legacy `SysV`? software itself is latest supported and current version (maybe they're doing this for compatibility (not sure))

Comment: That's my best guess. I don't have any old style init scripts handy to test with.

Comment: Which version of metricbeat is this? I just pulled the deb of the recently released 7.0.0 and it actually contains a proper systemd unit.

Comment: 7.0.0 just came out from beta the other day, 6.7.1 was latest before that.

Comment: Strange, the 6.7.1 deb has both a systemd unit and a sysv init script. systemd is supposed to ignore the init script in a case like this. You might have found a bug in Debian.

Comment: I've tried 7.0.0 for elasticsearch and `systemctl --now enable elasticsearch` works, I guess it's a bug with beats (rather then issue with `systemd`).